# No response using PyVISA from instrument on GPIB

Tags: python, visa, gpib, pyvisa

I'm trying to control an instrument (very old hall measurement device) on a GPIB with PyVISA. I know it works with labview, where I've found which addresses do what and some basic commands with a tracer but to no joy. I've been asked to write a DAQ and analytical code in python 3.

So far I've been able to identify the addresses:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())
>>>('ASRL1::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::0::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::1::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::3::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::4::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::5::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::6::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::7::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::8::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::9::INSTR', 'GPIB0::3::10::INSTR')
```

however when I try to query with any "wave" or indeed measurement command string (found tracing labview I/O) I am always met with a timeout error.

```
instr3_8 = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::3::8::INSTR')
instr3_8.query("*IDN?")
>>>VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

This is the result for everything I try to read from the instrument.

(PyVISA and the GPIB work with a Keithley source meter IDN query so I know the backend is working. The instrument is a bio-rad HL 5200 on the off chance that's of use to anyone, I've found no manual and next to no reference online.)

Here's an image of the [labview block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGJH.jpg) that reads the magnet position. I've since been able to change the position by writing with pyvisa but reading still gives a timeout, similar issues on github lead me to believe the termination character is wrong but I've no fix yet.

Comment: Could you post the labview code where it is working, than we might be able to see the differences.

Comment: As I understand it there's no accessible "code" outside of the block diagram in LabView but the tracer has everything that is sent to the instrument.

Comment: With "code" I meant the block diagram of labview, for us labview users this is actual code, you can post it as a image.

Comment: My apologies, I've put a link up to a simple recieve/read that works in labview but not python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came down to both PyVISA and NI MAX not recognising the termination characters when reading from the instrument. After trying all the possible termination characters with .read_termination I found one that worked can finally read from my hall probe.

Answer (score 0):

Very old GPIB instruments often have incomplete or non-standard implementation of GPIB. For example they can lack support for *IDN?, or have only one hard-coded command termination character.

Some of these old instrument also use address +1 as a 'printer' address. So the instrument reserves the address it is set to, but also the next one. This can be a cause of major confusion specially if there are more (old) instruments on the same network, so it is good idea never to use consequent addresses but go 1, 3, 5, 7 instead.

Also, even just polling the status byte too frequently can overload the processing capabilities of really old instruments, let alone reading the answer buffer.